# Java's add-opens doesn't seem to make a package accessible

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am trying to access JavaFX's package-private class & public static method in it (`javafx.scene.control.skin.TableSkinUtils.resizeColumnToFitContent`), so that I can resize TableView's columns automatically.

However, I'm using the module system since it seems that JavaFX 11 requires my app to be a module. If I don't specify a module for my app, I get this error: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application` I'd actually prefer to not use the module system at all, is there a way?

Now, due to the module system, I get an exception when attempting to make the method `TableSkinUtils.resizeColumnToFitContent` accessible:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public static void javafx.scene.control.skin.TableSkinUtils.resizeColumnToFitContent(javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkinBase,javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase,int) accessible: module javafx.controls does not "opens javafx.scene.control.skin" to module Explorer
```

So, I tried to add this workaround: `--add-opens javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED` to Intellij's run configuration VM options.

However, with or without the above, I get the same exception.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Explorer` instead of `ALL-UNNAMED`? In any case, I strongly suggest that you post a [mcve].

Comment: That was it, ALL-UNNAMED sounded a bit weird in the first place... I got it from another stackoverflow answer - without reading the answer completely. Thanks to both of you.